# Como acessar albuns de uma Fan Page no Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

Eu utilizava o seguinte codigo, para ter acesso aos albuns de uma fan page no facebook:

```
$cUrl = new cUrl;
$fb_page_id = "xxxx";

$json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields=id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count,created_time";
$json = $cUrl->file_get_contents_curl($json_link); 

/*$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);*/
$obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);

$album_count = count($obj['data']);

        for($x=0; $x<$album_count; $x++):

            $id = $obj['data'][$x]['id'];
            $name = $obj['data'][$x]['name'];
            /*$description = $obj['data'][$x]['description'];*/
            $link = $obj['data'][$x]['link'];
            $cover_photo = $obj['data'][$x]['cover_photo'];
            $count = $obj['data'][$x]['count'];
            $data_s-> usarData($obj['data'][$x]['created_time']);

            // if you want to exclude an album, just add the name on the if statement
            if(
                $name!="Profile Pictures" &&
                $name!="Untlited Album"
            ){
            $show_pictures_link = "?album_id={$id}&album_name={$name}";
            echo $data_s->data();
            echo "{$name}";                
            }
```

Tinha alguns HTML no código, mas não vem ao caso. Funcionava muito bem, mas agora não aparece nada. Alguém sabe o porque? ou tem um outro método?

Comment: Tem um espaço entre o `?` e os parametros `http://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/albums?   fields=id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count,created_time`, parece errado.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/album

Comment: Olá Guilherme, foi um erro na hora de organizar aqui na pergunta. Mas ele é pegado mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

O seu código tem erro mas o problema não é esse. Recentemente o Facebook mudou suas políticas e agora é preciso de um token para tal requisição.

Modifiquei o início de seu código, se você executar verá a mensagem "An access token is required to request this resource." .

```
// $cUrl = new cUrl;
$fb_page_id = "xxx";
$json_link = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/albums?fields=id,name,description,link,cover_photo,count,created_time";
// $json = $cUrl->file_get_contents_curl($json_link); 

$ch = curl_init($json_link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/*$obj = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);*/
$obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);
var_dump($obj);
exit;
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário Marcelo. Eu sou leigo nesse quesito, integração entre Facebook e Website, por mais que eu já tenha lido a documentação do mesmo. Você teria um exemplo de como seria esta integração? Sendo que meu objetivo é resgatar os albuns da Fan page, para serem exibidos no meu Site.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas respostas. Eu apenas inserir o Token de Acesso e deu tudo certo.